# Что определяет внешний вид окна DE или WM?

Tags: linux, desktop

Что определяет внешний вид окна Window Manager или Desktop Environment? А внешний вид кнопок, переключателей, текстовых полей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DE - это общее названия для множества программ, одной из которых являетcя WM. На то, как выглядит интерфейс, влияет только тема, написанная определённым человеком под определённое DE. А DE в свою очередь "объясняет" WM, как эту тему вырисовывать и как реагировать при взаимодействии c пользователем.